# My logo works in Firefox but not IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, css

My logo, which I'm referencing in my external css style sheet is working fine in Firefox, but does not appear to work in internet explorer:

below is the code I'm using:

```
#header
    {
    width: 760px; 
    float: left;
    background-color:  #fff;
}


#header h1
    {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}





#header h1 a
{

background:#fff url(images/logo.jpg) no-repeat;

width:290px; 

height: 75px;

float:left;

text-decoration:none;

}
```

Can anyone suggest a way in which I can get this logo to appear correctly in i.e?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: How is it not working, please provide more details, and your html or a link.

Comment: also, add a different color border to each element, then tell us what you see.

Answer (score 1):

try adding `overflow: hidden` to any floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display:block` to your #header h1 a class, If that still doesn't work, try changing your #header h1 a `background` to something like hot pink and verify its diminsions.

**Update:**  If your logo is collapsed try removing the float:left from that.  You already have float:left on the header and header h1.  You may also want to play around with a `clear` tag, or better yet, implement [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

Comment: good tip. I use borders though which let's you see an element, even if it's collapsed, which I think is what's going on here too.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely look for something like Firebug for IE (there must be something out there...) and then have a click-around. This isn't too scientific an approach, basically just trial-and-error, but I'm sure if the problem is something small like this, you could get to the bottom of it in no time this way :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

Actually, try using 
display: none; to get rid of the text in your header element combo'd with a "background:" definition.

Answer (score 0):

if your logo (image ) is CMYK it will not be displayed. Please make sure that your logo is RGB format, otherwise will not be supported in other browsers \

KosovoCustomDevelopment

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that IE considers the link as text and is therefore indenting the anchor instead of the text content inside the anchor.

Try moving your `text-indent` property into the rule of the anchor.

```
#header h1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#header h1 a
{
  background:#fff url(images/logo.jpg) no-repeat;
  width:290px; 
  height: 75px;
  float:left;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

Does that make any difference?